# Why sorting in the grid column works one time?

Tags: sorting, extjs, grid

I have à gridColumn with sort asc and desc.
The sort works one time.
I have to refresh my page to sort another time.
Normally we can click on the column name few times in a row and the sort should be done.

Actually the sort works the first time alter we need to reload.. or it should works without refresh the page.

Comment: Please share the issue fiddle

Comment: Sorry i don't understand the "fiddle". But my issue is, i have a column in the grid and i can sort one time only by clicking on the header column. I have to refresh the page to sort in an other sens...

Comment: The gridcolumn sort only in ASC sens, if i want to sort in DESC i have to refresh my page or another way is to sort another column before and then i can sort in DESC. 
But i can't sort the same column in ASC and just after in DESC.

Comment: Sencha fiddle link -> https://fiddle.sencha.com/

Over fiddle, you can create a sample example replicating the issue, which helps to address the issue easily. there might be cases where an override in your existing code base causes the issue. Or share code snippets along with version and toolkit details